# I get the following error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm', or '__attribute__' before '{' token. How do I fix it?

Tags: c

Check out the code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    float altura;
    float base;
    float area;
    float s;

    int main()
    {
        printf("altura:");
        scanf("%f",&altura);
        printf("base:");
        scanf("%f",&base);
        s=area;
        printf("el area es %f\n", area);
        return 0;
    }

    float area {
        float area;
        area = base+altura/2
        return area;
    }
```

Accept all suggestions

Comment: `float area{` --> `float area(void){`

Comment: Welcome to SO. As a new user, you may want to read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page some time -- your profile suggests you chose not to. As you can see, the vast majority of questions are in English. Also, please help us by properly formatting your code using the tools and hints in the editor.

Comment: Should this be on the Portuguese site?

Comment: @slugster Spanish and Portuguese are similar, but not interchangeable

Comment: Actually it is Spanish not Portuguese. Does Stack Overflow have other sites for different languages?

Comment: @Tom I couldn't tell the difference, it was just an educated guess :)

Comment: @Rafa Yes, there is a dedicated Portuguese version now, you can find it here: http://pt.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

You were missing a semicolon, and some variable names needed to be changed. Also, there needed to be parenthesis used when referring to your function (now called trianglerea):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
float altura;
float base;
float area;
float s;

float triangleArea (){
    float area;
    area = base*altura/2;
    return area;
}

int main()
{
    printf("altura:");
    scanf("%f",&altura);
    printf("base:");
    scanf("%f",&base);
    s=triangleArea();
    printf("el area es %f\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This Will Not Compile.

Comment: Edited. It now compiles.

Comment: Yep. :) That's also important.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whatever language is that, but I'll try...
I think you might be trying to calculate the area of a triangle? 3 edges?
Then you should be multiplying `altura` and `base`, like `altura * base`.
And then you should have put `()` after `float area`, like `float area();`.

Here, try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float altura;
float base;
float area();
float s;

int main( ) {
    printf( "altura:" );
    scanf( "%f", &altura );
    printf( "base:" );
    scanf( "%f", &base );
    s = area();
    printf( "el area es %f\n", s );
    return 0;
}

float area() {
    float area;
    area = base * altura / 2;
    return area;
}
```

Tried to keep it as familiar as I could...

Comment: thanks it really helped, thanks to you i noticed also de mistake at the formula